# Ativar campo ao carregar pagina caso input esteja preenchido com palavra especifica

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um formulário de cadastro que ao clicar em tipo de documento, caso seja "RG" tem uma função em JS que mostra um campo que esta definido em css como style="display: none".

Porem ao carregar da base ao fazer na pagina de update gostaria que ao carregar a pagina se o campo tipo de documento estiver preenchido com "RG" ai ativa a função para mostrar o campo emissor.

Utilizo esta função para ao trocar o campo tipo documento, se escolher "RG" mostra o campo emissor.

```
<script type="text/javascript" DEFER="DEFER">
  // INICIO FUNÇÃO DE MOSTRA ORGÃO EMISSOR
  window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('destypedoc').addEventListener('change', function () {
      var style = this.value == 'RG' ? 'block' : 'none';
      document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = style;
   });
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione isso dentro da função `window.onload`:

```js
var campoRG = document.getElementById('SEU_CAMPO_RG').value;
var display = campoRG.length > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';

document.getElementById('CAMPO_EMISSOR').style.display = display;
```

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição!

Comment: Perfeito funcionou muito bem obrigado